# Django - Reordering admin categories

Tags: django-admin, django-templates

I am hoping there is a way to do this without having to build and entire custom admin template.

I currently have the following:

```
Auth
-Groups
-Users

Book Content
-Book A
-Book B
-Book C
-etc.
```

The issue is that my models.py and views.py files are going to get way too large as there will be hundreds of Books, each with custom content. There are also multiple coders, so I would rather not have a coder need to wait for the views.py to be checked in if they are working on Book C when a different coder is working on Book B.

I played around with making each Book an App so that I can keep the models.py and views.py separated, but then I get:

```
Auth
-Groups
-Users

Book A
-Book A

Book B
-Book B

Book C
-Book C
```

I would like to go back to the original interface for the admin area, but keep each Book as a separate App. Is there a way in the admin.py to define an App is part of a different App? Or group App A, B, C together?

Answer (score -1):

try http://django-admin-tools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html